# Правило согласования для общего определения к нескольким существительным, которые связаны союзом "и"

Tags: согласование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким правилом нужно воспользоваться?

Пример для вопроса:
"По указанной серии и номеру" или "по указанным серии и номеру"?